# How to compare two calculated F objects

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm looking for a way to filter on a comparison of two fields calculated by `models.F`.

My models (simplified):

```
class Prescription(models.Model):
    treatment_count = models.SmallIntegerField()
    treatments_unregistered = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)

class Treatment(models.Model):
    prescription = models.ForeignKey(Prescription)
```

I calculate `max_treatments` as`treatment_count - treatments_unregistered`, and I calculate `actual_treatments` as the number of FKs `Treatment` has to `Prescription`. Both using annotation.

Now I'd like to filter all Prescriptions where the maximum Treatments is NOT met. Basically `actual_treatments` < `max_treatments`.

I tried the below but got `TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`.

> Prescription.objects.annotate(max_treatments=models.F('treatment_count')
>   - models.F('treatments_unregistered')).annotate(actual_treatments=models.Count('treatment')).filter(models.F('actual_treatments')
>   < models.F('max_treatments'))

I think I must be overlooking something in the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/) or [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters)?

If I'm not overlooking something obvious, what would be the best way to approach this?

Using Django 1.9.

Comment: First thing I'd try is `filter(actual_treatments__lt=models.F('max_treatments'))`. Note that arguments to `filter` are always keyword arguments, not boolean expressions like `<`. I haven't tried this on  `F` objects representing annotations, so there might still be complications.

Comment: Shouldn't `actual_treatments` be something like `models.Count('prescription')`, because of the fk relation?

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: I must've been sleepy when I tried this; I can indeed just reference the calculated `actual_treatments` without preceding `models.F`! So `.filter(actual_treatments__lt=models.F('max_treatments'))` **does** work. If you add your comment as an answer, I can accept.

Comment: @RodrigoDela: I don't think so; I'm doing the `.annotate()` on `Prescription` and have to count the number of `Treatment`s linked to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arguments to `filter` need to be in the form of `Q` objects or keyword arguments, rather than boolean expressions such as `<`. In this case, `filter(actual_treatments__lt=models.F('max_treatments'))`.